# Ambiguous column name error for user_id

Tags: sql, sqlite

My users table has the columns
`user_id`, `email`
My invites table has the columns
`invite_id`  `request_id`  `user_id`                   `sent_time`

When I run the following query, I get the two tables joined into 1, which is expected.

```
'SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN invites ON users.user_id = invites.user_id'
```

However, when I run the following query,

```
'SELECT user_id FROM users INNER JOIN invites ON users.user_id = invites.user_id'
```

I get the following error

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) ambiguous column name: user_id [SQL: 'SELECT user_id FROM users INNER JOIN invites ON users.user_id = invites.user_id']
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the message is pretty clear.  SQLite doesn't know what table `user_id` is coming from.

One simple solution is to qualify the column name usinga table alias:

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     invites i
     ON u.user_id = i.user_id;
```

Another method is to use `USING` rather than `ON`:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     invites i
     USING (user_id);
```

Comment: Why is `SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN invites ON users.user_id = invites.user_id` fine? I think after `users INNER JOIN invites`, there are two columns with the same name `user_id`, right?

Comment: @FeiZheng . . . The issue is when there is *one* column.  SQLite doesn't know what table it comes from.

Answer (score 1):

You need to qualify the column name with table name like below cause both table involved in query have the same column name

```
SELECT `users`.user_id 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN invites ON `users`.user_id = invites.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This means you need to be specific about *which* `user_id` column you want to display. Even though they're joined that doesn't guarantee they're identical. Some types of joins allow `NULL` values on one side of the match (e.g. `LEFT JOIN`), so you need to ask for a particular value:

```
SELECT users.user_id FROM users INNER JOIN invites ON users.user_id = invites.user_id
```